I cannot fix the error in the code? (EMU8086)
I was writing a number guessing game, but I keep getting an error in the mov al, 1h section on line 27. I tried mov ah, 1h. I tried mov ah, 01h and it failed again.
.model small
.stack 100h

.data
    prompt db '0 ile 9 arasinda bir sayi girin:', 0DH, 0AH, '$'
    mesaj_1 db 'Girdiginiz sayi çok küçük', 0DH, 0AH, '$'
    mesaj_2 db 'Girdiginiz sayi çok büyük', 0DH, 0AH, '$'
    mesaj_3 db 'Dogru tahmin\\\! Tebrikler\\\!', 0DH, 0AH, '$'
    mesaj_4 db 'Oyuncu Tanitimi', 0DH, 0AH, '$'

.code

start:
  ; Veri segmenti kayitlarini ayarlama
  mov ax, @data
  mov ds, ax

  ; Oyuncu tanitim mesajini görüntüleme
  mov dx, offset mesaj_4
  mov ah, 9h
  int 21h

  ; Rastgele sayi üretme fonksiyonunu çagir
  call rand_num

  ; Kullanicidan karsilastirma degerini alma (tek haneli sayi varsayilir)
  mov al, 1h; Karakter giris kesmesi (sistemlere göre degisebilir)
  int 21h   ; Kesmeyi baslatma

  ; Karsilastirma degerini CL'ye saklama
  mov cl, al  ; AL'yi (giris) CL'ye tasima

; -- Giris döngüsü baslangici ---
döngü:
  ; Istemi görüntüleme
  mov dx, offset prompt
  mov ah, 9h
  int 21h

  ; Kullanici girisini okuma
  mov ah, 01h ; Karakter giris kesmesi (sistemlere göre degisebilir)
  int 21h   ; Kesmeyi baslatma

  ; ASCII girisini sayisal degere dönüstürme
  sub al, 30h ; Sayisal degeri elde etmek için '0' (0'in ASCII degeri) çikarma

  ; Geçerli girisi kontrol etme (0-9)
  cmp al, 0     ; 0 ile karsilastirma
  jl invalid  ; 0'dan küçükse (geçersiz) atlama
  cmp al, 9     ; 9 ile karsilastirma
  jg invalid  ; 9'dan büyükse (geçersiz) atlama

  ; Girilen sayiyi karsilastirma degeriyle karsilastirma
  cmp al, cl
  jl smaller   ; Küçükse atlama
  jg bigger    ; Büyükse atlama
  je correct   ; Esitse atlama

; -- Giris döngüsü sonu ---

invalid:
  ; Geçersiz giris için hata mesaji görüntüleme
  mov dx, offset mesaj_5
  mov ah, 9h
  int 21h

  ; Geçerli giris almak için döngüye geri dön
  jmp döngü

smaller:
  ; Daha küçük sayi için mesaji görüntüleme
  mov dx, offset mesaj_1
  mov ah, 9h
  int 21h
  jmp döngü ; Döngüye geri dön

bigger:
  ; Daha büyük sayi için mesaji görüntüleme
  mov dx, offset mesaj_2
  mov ah, 9h
  int 21h
  jmp döngü ; Döngüye geri dön

correct:
  ; Dogru tahmin için mesaji görüntüleme
  mov dx, offset mesaj_3
  mov ah, 9h
  int 21h

  ; Oyunu bitirme
  mov ah, 4ch  ; Program sonlandirma kesmesi (sistemlere göre degisebilir)
  int 21h

; -- Rastgele sayi üretme fonksiyonu ---
rand_num:
  mov ax, 1345h  ; Seed degeri (degistirilebilir)
  int 21h       ; Kesmeyi baslat (DOS için)
  mov bx, ax     ; Rastgele sayiyi BX'e tasi

  ret            ; Fonksiyondan dön

; -- Hata mesaji ---
mesaj_5 db 'Geçersiz bir sayi gir




(27) wrong parameters: MOV  al, 1h
(27) probably no zero prefix for hex; or no 'h' suffix; or wrong addressing; or undefined var:  1h
""

I keep getting these errors.

Works fine here. Make sure you are using the exact source you posted. Also delete the line and re-type it in case it contains some unicode garbage. Also 1 is 1 in every base so no need for hex (but it should work).


an error in the mov al, 1h section on line 27. I tried mov ah, 1h.

It is strange that you say you gave it a 'try' with swapping ah for al. The function number for any of the DOS functions must mandatory be placed in the AH register. There's no guessing involved.

; Kullanicidan karsilastirma degerini alma (tek haneli sayi varsayilir)
mov al, 1h; Karakter giris kesmesi (sistemlere göre degisebilir)
int 21h   ; Kesmeyi baslatma



; Kullanici girisini okuma
mov ah, 01h ; Karakter giris kesmesi (sistemlere göre degisebilir)
int 21h   ; Kesmeyi baslatma


What does immediately strike me is that the offending line is the only line in your program where you have started the tail-comment directly after the instruction, so with no intervening whitespace.
emu8086 is notoriously known for its many bugs, so I wouldn't be surprised that this is the reason for the error message(s).
I suggest you stick with mov ah, 01h  ; Comment.

On the subject of the number guessing game. The user will never be able to guess the number as the cmp al, cl instruction is comparing items that are not on the same level! In casu, you have converted the user's guess in AL from character ["0","9"] to number [0,9], but the CL register still contains the unconverted character from the initial input.


; -- Rastgele sayi üretme fonksiyonu ---
rand_num:
  mov ax, 1345h  ; Seed degeri (degistirilebilir)
  int 21h        ; Kesmeyi baslat (DOS için)
  mov bx, ax     ; Rastgele sayiyi BX'e tasi
  ret            ; Fonksiyondan dön


I only partially understand these comments since there're not in English, but I am pretty sure this code has nothing to do with random numbers or seeds thereof. The DOS function 13h is used to delete a file based on a File Control Block (FCB). Best to remove this from your program.
